# How can I get Riding and the gold to afford it in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm a level 28 Night Elf and am trying to buy a mount and Riding training.  How can I raise gold to afford this, and where can I buy the appropriate mount and Riding?

Comment: I edited your question so that it hopefully reflects what you needed to know, instead of what you asked, and to make it more useful for others. :)

Comment: Ask a friend to give or lend you the gold. Later on you will replay him easily.

Comment: Really this consists of two questions: Where can I train my riding skill? and How can I get gold quickly?

Comment: Should be split into 2 questions. What you're raising money for doesn't really matter to the process of raising money.

Answer (score 3):

At that level the best way to get gold is to choose Mining and Herbalism as your two Professions, then do loops of areas mining and herbing, and auctioning the results.  You can get sufficient gold quite quickly.

Having said that, these days levelling should give you more than enough gold to provide for your needs.  [Riding](http://www.wowhead.com/skill=762/riding) in particular should cost 4g for the basic skill and 1g for the mount as required at level 20.  At level 40 you can get a slightly faster ground mount for 50g for the skill and 10g for the mount, but that shouldn't be a concern as yet.

To get the Riding and mount versions you can use, you can visit [Darlene Stokx](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=43693) in Stormwind to purchase Apprentice Riding.  You then need to visit [Katie Stokx](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=43694) (next to Darlene) to buy a mount of your choice that you can now ride for 1g.

Comment: I went to the Griffon Vendor in Stormwind and a Golden Griffen is 45g but the skill i need is 225g (300g is a rough estimate) Thanks for replying!

Comment: Those are flying mounts that you only have access to at level 60 and above.  I've updated the answer to let you know where you can find the level-appropriate Riding.

Comment: Thx! I appreciate it

Comment: Soo..Lets say i have 20 Peaceblooms=2 Silver. What would i sell it for?...Keeping in mind i would need profit...

Comment: Have a look at the Auction House to see what it's selling for currently, then price it around the same as the lowest price.  Usually it's 1-5g per stack for herbs, more for ore.  Rinse and repeat.